# Unable to access a locally hosted wcf service over the internet

Tags: wcf

i have hosted a wcf service in our office machine and which is being accessible from other pc in LAN. our office has static IP. so how can i access my wcf service from the out side of office if i know the static ip of our office.

now i am accessing the service from lan using this url `http://192.168.6.2:7741/Services/CustomerService`

if our office static ip is **122.160.187.236** then can i access my service just replace the ip address with static ip address ? please tell me all require steps to access wcf service over the internet. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to forward the port 7741 on the router to the 192.168.6.2 IP address.

You'll have to ask someone who has access to the router to do this.
Not sure what your environment is like but on your general router these settings will generally fall under 'advanced settings > NAT

Check out http://portforward.com/ for info on port forwarding.

Also, if you have a firewall, you need to ensure that traffic via port 7741 is allowed.

This is probably the quickest way to achieve what you want, but not the most secure. Establishing a VPN would be better but I'm not going to open that can of worms now.

Niel

Comment: which url i need to use to access wcf service from out side. how my url would look then? thanks

Comment: If you've forwarded your ports it would look like this: http://122.160.187.236:7741/Services/CustomerService - You replace the local IP with your public IP, the router wil then know to send the traffic to the correct local IP

Comment: so u mean just doing port forwarding i can access my service from out side....nothing else config is required?

Comment: You should be able to, unless you have a complicated network with proxies and firewalls etc. Your network administrator should know exactly what to do although larger companies may have some policies that could delay the process.

Comment: another question on port forwarding.lots of tool is freely available for forwarding port with entering into router settings. is it true that by any tool i can forward port from my pc in a network. lots of c# library is also available too.one is called barbara tunnel in codeproject.com.

Answer (score 0):

it's not enough to know only IP of your network if you want access your machine from outside. Probably you should talk to administrator of your network to either establish virtual private network or assign external IP address to your machine. Actually the question related mostly to network administration and configuration, but not to WCF.

Comment: u said:- assign external IP address to your machine. this is not clear to me what r u trying to say assign external IP address to your machine.can u plzz discuss it more details.thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your WCF Service from outside your LAN, from the internet, you need to assign a DNS Server outside on the internet that can assign to you a public static IP Address, because your LAN is most probably using a DHCP to lease a temporary static private IP Address. Some DNS server are free and other you need to pay a monthly fee.