# Access to a self-hosted WCF service on azure virtual machine over the Internet

Tags: windows, wcf, azure

Actually the question is kind of duplication of the following one [Unable to access a locally hosted wcf service over the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277817/unable-to-access-a-locally-hosted-wcf-service-over-the-internet) but **with only difference that the service is hosted by a windows service on Azure Virtual Machine**.

I can access the service on the machine and I have added an endpoint to the service port at Azure Configuration console, but still cannot access the service over the Internet.

The error message that is not possible to set up connection.

Is my scenario technical possible on azure? if yes - what is done wrong?

Comment: Did you use localhost in our window service or a public url?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question was pretty straightforward. Although I opened my endpoint in Azure Management Console the port was blocked by the virtual machine firewall (windows firewall). After setting in- and out- tcp port rule, the problem had gone.

Comment: I added the rules to allow the particular port, in firewall. Still I am unable to access.

Comment: Can you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162250/unable-to-access-a-self-hosted-wcf-service-on-azure-virtual-machine

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me. My case was the same.