# Unable to access a self-hosted WCF service on azure virtual machine

Tags: wcf, azure, firewall, azure-virtual-machine, self-hosting

I have self-hosted a WCF service on base adress `new Uri("http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":1235/myService")` on an Azure Virtual Machine. I have printed this address and I get it as `http://TRIALVM:1235/IRChatbotService`. The DNS name of my virtual machine is `trialvm.cloudapp.net`.

As I have hosted this service on port 1235, I have added the inbound rule with following properties:

[image]

Still the created service is not accessible from outside VM. I am able to get service page when I go to the service URL `http://TRIALVM:1235/IRChatbotService` on the same virtual machine, but not from my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the endpoint on the Azure portal. By default the machine is firewalled from Azure as well...not just your VM.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

Comment: suggested solution shoutd work for sure! so 2 steps to be done: open 1235 tcp port over AzurePortal, open 1235 port over windows firewall on the azure machine, from remote machine use http://trialvm.cloudapp.net:1235/IRChatbotService And... sure you should be aware that the service is hosted and running

Answer (score 0):

If you're using http://TRIALVM:1235/IRChatbotService to access the web service from outside the VM it won't work.  TRAILVM is the hostname which is resolvable within the cloud service but from the outside world you need the domain name of the cloud service/load balancer, in this case both the VM and the cloud service are called trialvm but they can be different as you can have many vms in a cloud service.  In this case the domain name looks to be trialvm.cloudapp.net.

Hth,
Gareth